# How can I add the most frequent `url` and the corresponding `typology`?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
+-----+--------+-----+--------+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------------+
|srcId|srcLabel|dstId|dstLabel|attr|                 url|typology|minTimestamp|maxTimestamp|
+-----+--------+-----+--------+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------------+
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://ecodiario....|    news|  1484237640|  1484237640|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://ecodiario....|    news|  1485181440|  1485181440|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1485506280|  1485506280|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484657400|  1484657400|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484885100|  1484885100|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1483505700|  1483505700|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1483678680|  1483678680|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484383380|  1484383380|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484833200|  1484833200|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484840760|  1484840760|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1483372380|  1483372380|
|    0|       i|    0|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484852760|  1484852760|
|    0|       i|    1|       i| 1.0|http://ecodiario....|    news|  1484344140|  1484344140|
|    0|       i|    1|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484472840|  1484472840|
|    0|       i|    1|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1485600720|  1485600720|
|    0|       i|    2|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1485882600|  1485882600|
|    0|       i|    3|       i| 1.0|http://ecodiario....|    news|  1485244920|  1485244920|
|    0|       i|    3|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1485178740|  1485178740|
|    0|       i|    7|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1483979640|  1483979640|
|    0|       i|    8|       i| 1.0|http://www.elecon...|    news|  1484041200|  1484041200|
+-----+--------+-----+--------+----+--------------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

I need to delete duplicated combinations of `srcId` and `dstId`, while leaving the row with the most frequent value of `url`, the earliest `minTimestamp` and latest `maxTimestamp`.

How can I do it?

I have this part of code:

```
df
  .groupBy("srcId","srcLabel","dstId","dstLabel")
  .agg(min("minTimestamp").as("minTimestamp"),max("maxTimestamp").as("maxTimestamp"))
```

How can I add the most frequent `url` and the corresponding `typology`?

Answer (score 1):

You're aggregating over 2 different groups, so as far as I'm aware you'll have to join. Something like this should work:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("srcId", "dstId").orderBy(count(lit(1)) desc)
val urls = df.groupBy("srcId", "dstId", "url", "typology")
    .agg(row_number() over w as "rn")
    .where("rn == 1")
    .alias("counts")

val result = df.groupBy("srcId", "dstId")
    .agg(
        min("minTimestamp").as("minTimestamp"),
        max("maxTimestamp").as("maxTimestamp"))
    .join(urls, Seq("srcId", "dstId"), "inner")
```